# ERROR occurs in Bots open source EDI Software

Tags: bots

I developing a very big project in which we have to use a "Bots open source EDI tranlation tool." 
Bots uses a pythen script to convert a edi file to specified file (i.e. xml, csv, x12, database, etc).
Bots have their own plugins for learning purpose in which a user can come to know that how the bots working ? and how work done through ?
My problem is if i use it's ready made plugins then it works
But when i try to input file myself it doesn't work it generates an error that File got stuck. what is the problem with that i can't understand
If anybody of who know regarding this Pls. help me
I got exousted with this problem.

Comment: Bots plugins stop working after unzipping and zipping it back. I checked original zip file and zip after unzipping/zipping and they have different size and look different in DIFF. It has probably something to do with encoding, but I am new to python and don't know how you Python guys deal with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'd better try the mail forum for bots open source edi software?